# remove nested object references mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have several mongoose models in my application - assignment, submisssion, and file.

```
var assignmentSchema = new Schema({
    submissions:[{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Submission'
    }]
});
```

---

```
var submissionSchema = new Schema({
    assignment: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Assignment'
    },
    files: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'File'
    }],
})
```

---

```
var fileSchema = new Schema({
    submission: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Submission'
    }
})
```

I defined a remove hook for assignments, so when an assignment is removed from my mongodb, all submissions are deleted too.

```
assignmentSchema.pre('remove', function (next) {
    var assignment = this;

    assignment.model('Class').update(
        {_id: {$in: assignment.classes}},
        {$pull: {assignments: assignment._id}},
        {multi: true},
        next
    );

    //will delete all submissions that were in the assignment
    assignment.model('Submission').remove(
        {_id: {$in: assignment.submissions}}).exec();
        next
});
```

It works ok, but I also want to remove all files that are related to deleted submissions. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to setup a pre remove hook for your submission documents.
Then in your assignmentSchema loop through the assignment.submissions array, find each assignment document and execute a remove on that document. 
Here is an example. Not tested.

```
assignmentSchema.pre('remove', function(nextAction) {
    var assignment = this;

    assignment.model('Class').update({
            _id: {
                $in: assignment.classes
            }
        }, {
            $pull: {
                assignments: assignment._id
            }
        }, {
            multi: true
        },
        next
    );

    Async.each(assignment.submissions, function(subId, next) {
        submissionSchema.findById(subId).exec(function(err, submission) {
            submission.remove();
            next();
        })
    }, function() {
        nextAction();
    })
});



submissionSchema.pre('remove', function (next) {
///remove files here.
})
```